# OSX internal microphone picks up the internal speaker output in Python

Tags: python, macos, voice, pyaudio

I am working on adding a voice interface to a chatbot in Python on OSX.

I'm using `pyaudio` to record the voice and play the response. Recording and playing are done simultaneously so that the user can interrupt the chatbot.

Everything works fine except that the internal microphone input picks up the internal speaker output and the Speech-To-Text engine transcribes what the speaker is playing. I can use a headphone to fix this, but I need to use the internal microphone and speaker for demo purposes.

I guess I need a kind of `Acoustic Echo Cancellation`. I have been looking into it but could not figure out a method which works.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is "Ambient Noise Reduction" on?

Comment: Yes, it's on. I tried with both on and off, neither worked.